# Can methods in Jython return Java objects?

Tags: java, swing, jython

I am using Marathon to test a Java Swing Application. A testing tool for Java Swing applications using Jython. Throughout the scope of this question I'm only concerned with two python files.

CallingFile.py:

```
    testObject = getParentOfFooJPanel(get_component('...'))
    print(testObject.getClass().getSimpleName()) #this is only here for testing
                                                 #if my code works, but this is
                                                 #where I get the errors
```

FileWithMethod.py

```
    def getParentOfFooJPanel(startingComponent):
        if (startingComponent.getClass().getSimpleName() == 'FooJPanel')

            print(startingComponent.getClass().getSimpleName()) #prints what I would expect
            print(startingComponent.getParent().getClass().getSimpleName()) #prints what I would expect
            return(startingComponent.getParent())

        else:

            getParentOfFooJPanel(startingComponent.getParent())
```

Whenever I try to reference the object in the FileWithMethod.py it behaves as I would expect it to. However, when I return the component(Java object) and try to use it in the CallingFile.py (for now where I call to print the simple name) it says that 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getClass'. Can Jython not return Java objects? If not, are there any work arounds?

Comment: Not sure, but you may need a return for the recursive call to getParentOfFooJPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jython can definitely return Java objects.  Below is an example of returning an object.

Your error most likely means some other bug in your code is returning `None`.

CallingFile.py:

```
from FileWithMethod import getStringReader
testObject = getStringReader("Hello World")
print(type(testObject))
```

FileWithMethod.py

```
import java.io.StringReader
def getStringReader(string):
    return java.io.StringReader(string)
```

Running it:

```
$ jython CallingFile.py
<type 'java.io.StringReader'>
```

Comment: I have replaced `return startingComponent.getParent()` with `return java.awt.Component(startingComponent.getParent()`, but now I get the error no visible constructor because java.awt.Component only have one constructor and it is protected. I have read that you can tell Jython to ignore Java accessibility, but I'd rather not do that unless I absolutely have to.

Comment: Also, Component is an abstract class so I can't really cast it to a Component object.

Comment: I can only answer your question: "yes, Jython methods can return Java objects".  I can't write your code for you; if you have code that cannot return objects, you need to figure out why your code can't do that.

Comment: I'm not asking you to write code for me. I just can't figure out why `return startingComponent.getParent()` returns 'NoneType' object, but when I call into another method (inside FileWithMethod) with same exact thing it is treated as a component object like I would expect. If I can't return the thing, but can pass it to another method then it has to do with not being able to pass the object from file to file is all I'm saying. I found a workaround anyway. Thanks for your comments and time.